# Getting NullPointerException during starting JasperReports Server deployed on Tomcat

Tags: ireport, tomcat7, jasperserver

I'm trying to use *JasperReports Server* from *iReport*. 
I got this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669500/getting-java-net-connectexception-during-setup-jr-server-configuration-in-irepor). I solve this issue.

Then I get this error when I start *Tomcat* via *startup.bat*.

```
ERROR ContextLoader,localhost-startStop-1:307-Context initialization failed java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.hibernat
e.HibernateRepositoryServiceImpl.getMaxUriLength(HibernateRepositoryServiceImpl.
java:1785)....
```

I don't get it why this happen. I installed *JR Server* almost ten times, but result did not change. I think, this error cause (404) not found exception what I told before, but I am not sure.

Comment: Ayşegül did you solve this problem?